# How to show ProgressiDialog when using LoaderCallbacks

Tags: android, classloader, progressdialog, contentobserver

I have a class that loads the images on the device. This is an example of my activity:

```
public class MediaListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ...
        progressDialog.show();            
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }


    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {    
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {    
        progressDialog.dismiss();   
    }

}
```

Of course, I can't put `progressDialog.show()` inside the `onCreate()` method, since if the `ContentObserver` find a change in `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` and the `Cursor` is reloaded the method `progressDialog.show()` will not be called.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can show progress dialog inside onCreateLoader method. You have to use onLoaderReset method to handle a change in media  content. You can dismiss dialog here.

Comment: onCreateLoader is called only once, when the loader is created. Is not called every time a new load is executed.
When there is a change inside MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, onCreateLoader is not called

Answer (score 0):

Try showing the dialog in onLoaderReset() callback. It is called anytime a loader is restarted, despite the onCreateLoader() that may not be called every time because the loader might already be created.